# Animating background color, pulse effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have made a script for animating my menu li element after mouseovering the a element inside it.

Everything works fine, but I want something else. I want the effect not to disappear but to linger as long as the mouse is over the a element.

What function to use?

Script so far:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".main-navigation a").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({
    backgroundColor: "green"
    }, "normal"),
    $(this).parent().animate({
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().animate({
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }, "normal")
    });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neugu8r9/

Comment: You can do this with just CSS3, in IE9+.

Comment: I have managed to create a full Jquery solution for you, knock your self out :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this using CSS's `@keyframes` without jQuery.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
li a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a:hover:before {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: pulse 0.8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Menu-item#1</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu-item#2</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu-item#3</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu-item#4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, I want the hovering to happen on a not on li. And still no "pulsing" effect there as well.

Comment: @chipCholocate.py This is pulsating indeed! Amazing ;o Had no idea css can do this. But, this is not really smooth. It's like semaphore. Just turns out turns out. I want it smooth like when you animate opacity for example. Is it possible? EDIT: Nevermind, i slowed it down 0.8 to 2s transition and it works okay. It's just a bit mal positioned. Trying to fix that with css.

Comment: @NikolaL. - Ofcourse CSS is capable of such things.

Comment: this almost hits the net! There's just one downfall. When it goes to green it animates pretty well, but from green to transparent it's instant, no transition effect.

Comment: @NikolaL. May I inquire you to read up on [**css animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) always remembering the [**compatibility messures**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) you need to take to make them work in all modern browsers? You'll be surprised.

Comment: @NikolaL. - You could play around with the `@keyframes` rules(`0% {} 50% {} 100%`), change them to different percentage values or even add more to get the desired effect.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Wow, I just re-read what I wrote, no, not at all! He said he didn't know css could do that, so I asked for him to read up on css animations, saying he can be surprised about how much can be accomplished, but always remembering to use the appropiate prefixes! Sorry it came out that way :)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py No prob, also, seems like Nikola here is missing an alternate in his `animation` declaration, if it just cuts away like that :)

Comment: @Rou - Thanks for the links. I'll take a look at them.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py. Yes, I think I get it. I've used 25% and 75% as midpoitns and set to some color that is between the white and the green. So, I think it will do nice. I'd still like to have a jQuery solution though. If nobody replies to this I will select your answer tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: You are right not a full Jquery Solution but now it is. Hope you like it:)  By the way  cool CSS from you +1

Comment: Why do you have to write the keyframes multpile times with -webkit and without it.  Isn't this supposed to be a standard?  Why the non-standard implementations at all?

Comment: @Triynko - `-webkit-` declaration is to support `-webkit-` browsers.

Comment: Thank you!  Very good answer and demonstration!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Full jQuery solution for you buddy, hope it helps:=)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var intervalID;

    $(".main-navigation ul li a").hover(function(){ 

    var that = $(this); 
     var opacityToggle = function(){
        if(!that.children('.green').length){
         $(that).prepend('<span class="green"></span>');
            $('.green').animate({opacity:1},500);
        }
        else if(that.children('.green').length){
         
       $('.green').animate({opacity:0},500,function(){
       $('.green').remove();
       });
       }
            
     
   }
    
  intervalID = setInterval(opacityToggle, 500);    

},function(){
 $('.green').remove(); 
clearInterval(intervalID);
intervalID = 0;     
});
});
```

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
}

li a {
height:100%;    
text-align:center;
position:relative;
width:inherit;
display:block;

}

li {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

.green{
position:absolute;
background-color:green; 
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
opacity:0;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Menu-item#1</a></li>
        <li><a>Menu-item#2</a></li>
        <li><a>Menu-item#3</a></li>
        <li><a>Menu-item#4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That is not a jQuery solution, you are using CSS for the animation and jQuery to toggle classes.

Comment: @Dejo I will check this tomorrow. Haven't had time today.

Comment: Nema problema lega:=)

Comment: @Dejo Dekic. Dejo, there's a problem here. This is animating the <a> element instead of its parent <li>. If you could just change that (I'm not sure myself how to do it.) Hvala.

Comment: No it is NOT animating <a> or <li> element... what script does is dynamically creating a span element ('with green class') and than changes its opacity and removes that element...

Comment: I think it is the best way to do it using jQuery because you can't animate element backgroud color (using jQuery only without any plugins)